# Apexchart hiding the xaxis dialog when hovering the chart

Tags: apexcharts

Please take a look at [this](https://codepen.io/zolash/pen/bxJogV) for example.

I'm not sure about what apexcharts calls this so let me explain: 
 the little dialog that pops up on the `xaxis` (beside the tooltip) when you hover the chart: [image]

I don't want that dialog to pop up when user hovers the chart.
I tried setting `crosshair` of the `xaxis` to false like this:

```
xaxis: {
    categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    crosshairs: {
        show: false,
    }
}
```

But that didn't work. I guess that is not what it's called. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the "x axis tooltip"; in apexcharts each axis has its own tooltip, in addition to the chart's tooltip, see [the docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#tooltip) on `xaxis`.

Its options are defined under `xaxis.tooltip`. To disable it, just set its `enabled` property to `false`:

```js
    xaxis: {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
```